# Can we link an .asmx to an asp.net control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, webservice-client

I have a .asmx file that I use to give the data to my **AutoCompleteExtender** (Ajax AutoCompleteExtender from the **AJAX Toolkit**). That AutoCompleteExtender communicate with a stored procedure in a SQL Database.

Here is the problem: the user can choose a filter to search the database (Name, address, title, etc). That filter is applied with with a DropDownList. If I want my AutoComplete to work properly, I must apply the filter on the AutoComplete. I currently try using the **SelectedIndex** of the DropDownList to apply the filter.

ie: If the user select address, I must not give AutoComplete suggestions for the names.

If I put a filter by default in the .asmx file, the AutoComplete works (ie: the names), the sql procedure does not have any problems, nor does the aspx page. I want to know if there is a way for me to get the SelectedIndex of the DropDownList in the .asmx file or any alternative of doing the same thing.

Here is the code

**TextBox + AutoCompleteExtender:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"  style="margin-bottom: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtenderSearchValue" runat="server" ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" 
    ServiceMethod="GetSuggestions"  TargetControlID="txtValue" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="10"
    EnableCaching="true" UseContextKey="true" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Function to get my data for the AutoCompleteExtender in the .asmx:

```
//will get all the suggestions from what the user typed.
public string[] GetSuggestions(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    string name = null;
    string surname = null;
    string givenName = null;
    string title = null;
    string phone = null;
    string department = null;
    string location = null;
    DataTable dt = null;

    List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
    dt = new DataTable("Users");

    //pr_SEL_Usr
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigManager.SelUser);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //set the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = surname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GivenName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = givenName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = phone;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Division", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = department;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = location;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_cd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = null;

    dt = DBUtils.Execute(cmd);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < count)
            suggestions.Add(dt.Rows[i][5].ToString());
        else
            break;
    }

    return suggestions.ToArray();
}
```

I have tried adding a variable index to the function and using a case to set the parameter, but that did not work. I've searched the internet for a way to do that but to no avail.
.net

Comment: FYI, please use "ASP.NET", not "ASP" both in tags and in your title. "ASP" could refer to "ASP 3.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` on your filter dropdownlist.

Add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event to the filter dropdownlist. In that event method, set the `ContextKey` property of the `AutoCompleteExtender`.

```
protected void FilterDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteExtenderSearchValue.ContextKey = FilterDropDownList.SelectedValue;
}
```

Now your `GetSuggestions` ASMX method should receive the filter dropdownlist value via the `contextKey` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for your web service to reference controls on your page. At the time your JavaScript calls the service, the page object no longer exists, anyway.

You could conceivably make your web service use session state. You could then add a new call to pass the filter settings from your page to the service. When the autocomplete extender calls the service, that filter information would still be in Session state, where you stored it in the previous call.